# How to make sql more efficient. Need just the count

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I need to find number of users:

1. who have one or more fans
2. who have two fans
3. who have three fans

Here is the sql I developed to get answer to the #1

```
  SELECT users.id, count(fans.id)
    FROM users 
    JOIN fans on users.id = fans.user_id
GROUP BY users.id
  HAVING COUNT(fans.id) > 0
```

Above query works but I am getting all the user records and then I am calculating the size of the array. It has terrible performance when the number of users is in thousands.  How do I refactor the query so that I could get only the count of users?

I am using mysql, but I might need for another project using postgresql.

Comment: Isn't all the information you need is in the table "fans"? I don't see a reason to join the "users" table at all. If you have a performance problem with only thousands of rows, make sure your statistics are up to date, and look at the query's execution plan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A subquery will do nicely.

```
Select 
  Count(user.id) 
from 
  Users 
Where 
  (Select Count(fans.id) from Fans where user_id = users.id) > 0
```

Comment: That worked like charm. Thank you. Also learned something new today.

Comment: I think @Nicholas Carey answer has the less overhead and give's all the three options you asked. Since you find the above ok you could try SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user.id) FROM Fans

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
select usersWithOneOrMoreFans = sum( case when t.fan_count >= 1 then 1 else 0 end ) ,
       usersWithTwoFans       = sum( case when t.fan_count =  2 then 1 else 0 end ) ,
       usersWithThreeFans     = sum( case when t.fan_count =  3 then 1 else 0 end )
from ( select user_id as user_id   ,
              count(*) as fan_count ,
       from fans
       group by fans.user_id
     ) t
```

[edited to remove pointless table reference]

Comment: wow. I had no idea one could write like a real programming language code in sql. I wish I could split the point with you.

Comment: SQL **is** a real programming language, Turing-complete and all. It's just not a **procedural** language. It's all about set manipulation. Not that this is to say that SQL is suitable for general purpose work: it's designed for a specific problem space.

Answer (score 0):

```
select num_users_with_fans, num_users_with_two_fans,num_users_with_three_fans
from(
    select count(1) as num_users_with_fans
    from(
        select users.id, count(fans.id)
         from users join fans on users.id = fans.user_id
         group by users.id
         having count(fans.id) > 0
    )a
cross join(
    select users.id, count(fans.id) as num_users_with_two_fans
     from users join fans on users.id = fans.user_id
     group by users.id
     having count(fans.id)=2
)b
cross join(
    select users.id, count(fans.id) as num_users_with_three_fans
     from users join fans on users.id = fans.user_id
     group by users.id
     having count(fans.id)=3
)c
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's mine :

```
 SELECT nfans, count(*) AS nusers FROM
     (SELECT count(fans.id) AS nfans FROM fans GROUP BY user_id) foo
 GROUP BY nfans
```

This will give you the number of users "nusers" which have "nfans" fans.

If you want to clip the output to maximum 3 fans :

```
 SELECT nfans, count(*) AS nusers FROM
     (SELECT least(3,count(fans.id)) AS nfans FROM fans GROUP BY user_id) foo
 GROUP BY nfans
```

In this case, the bin "nfans=3" contains the number of users which have 3 or more fans.